# Can a call file search for available channels?

Tags: asterisk

I'm writing a robocaller for a company on a server which also has incoming calls. I have an AMI poll set up that will make sure there is a certain number of available channels before it pushes a call file through, but I don't know which specific channels will be open. Since I can't be sure at the time of generating my .call files which channels will be open, is there a way to automatically assign free channels to a call the way incoming/transferred/bridged channels are automatically assigned, or is this only possible within the dial plan? If it is possible outside of the dial plan, what would you recommend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is only possible with dialplan, you need in case of any call initiated check if src/dst channel is reserved by robocaller. There is also another way: listen AMI events, check for new channels, in case of reserved channel usage - send Hangup for this channel.

Comment: I'd rather not hang up on the incoming calls-- I'll find another way. Thank you anyways.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who finds this via search, I found a better way.

You start by calling a local channel using your .call file. Be sure to set a PHONENUMBER variable in the call file to the number you ultimately want to call. We then find an available channel and call it like this:

```
exten => 1,1,ChanIsAvail(Appropriate channels here); Checks if those channels are available and assigns ${AVAILORIGCHAN} an available channel
exten => 1,2,Dial(${AVAILORIGCHAN}${PHONENUMBER}/n); Dials the phone number on the available channel. The /n is very important if you plan on changing CDR variables after the call goes through. Otherwise, leave it out.
exten => 1,3,Hangup(); Clean up the local channel when we're done with it.
```

This is going to forward your callee to the context and extension listed in the CONTEXT and EXTENSION variables in the call file.